# htaccess redirect to index.php?idApp with https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder in `/var/www/MyApp/`

There is a `index.php` file.

There is a .htaccess file in `/var/www/MyApp/` with this content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oauthcallback.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^index.php?][^/]+)$ index.php?idApp=$1 [L]
```

in the `/var/www/MyApp/index.php`

I have:

`$myAppUrl = $_GET['idApp'];`

...

This works fine with `http`, when you go to http://www.example.com/MyApp/TheBestApp

`$myAppUrl is "TheBestApp"`

But this redirect does not work with https.

I need when you go to https://www.example.com/MyApp/TheBestApp does the same behavour.

How can i do it ?

Comment: I would suspect that the issue is that you have `index.php` registered as default index document and that your redirection forwards to ``/``. not to ``/index.php``. That means that in such cases your rewrite rule does not get applied.

Comment: Thanks arkascha, and how could i do to fix it ?

Comment: Well, you could add another rewrite rule explicitly reacting to that request, couldn't you?

Comment: The problem is solved with this configuration in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf # Esto permite que los .htaccess funcionen
 <Directory "/var/www">
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
 </Directory>